Underestimation of Empirical Coefficient of Variation When Sampling from a Log-Normal Distribution with High CV
I am working with a log-normal distribution where I input a coefficient of variation (CV) to generate the variance. I then sample  times from this distribution. The issue I am encountering is that for high CV values (e.g., CV = 10), the empirical CV, calculated as the standard deviation of the  samples divided by their mean, consistently underestimates the true CV.
For instance, when I set the CV to 10 and take samples, the empirical CV calculated from the samples is approximately 6, which is significantly lower than the input CV. I understand that the log-normal distribution is skewed, especially with higher CV values, and this can affect the sample statistics.
Here are some additional constraints and considerations:
I cannot increase the sample size, so increasing  is not an option.
I’ve tried bias correction but even with this correction, the CV remains too low.
I understand the log-normal distribution's skewness plays a role here, but I’m unsure how to address this properly in the calculation.
My question is: How can I accurately estimate the CV when sampling from a log-normal distribution with very high CV values without increasing the sample size? Are there alternative methods to better capture the true CV, given the constraints? Any suggestions for robust or transformation-based approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Unbiasing it may prove difficult. What estimator are you using now? How important is bias in the estimator compared to variance? The distribution of typical estimators of sd/mean will themselves be skewed, so even with an unbiased estimator it might usually be too small.

With a CV that large, you would have to generate an enormous number of samples before having any appreciable chance of reproducing the underlying moments of the distribution.  As a rule of thumb, once the CV exceeds $1$ you are getting into trouble and relying heavily on the assumption of lognormality for almost any estimation.  As far as "accurately estimating" goes, that comes down to what you mean specifically.  Should the estimate be unbiased? They exist, at least approximately, but have even larger sampling variances than other estimates.

If I didn't make a calculation error just now, for a population CV of 10 your $\sigma$ parameter is around 2.15; this is quite high for a lognormal (e.g. the skewness of this distribution is over 1000 and the mean is about 10 times the median. There are better estimators  (in a couple of senses) than $s/\bar{y}$ but none will work very well unless your sample sizes are very far into the thousands.

Thank you for the answers! To clarify I am performing simulations where I draw a parameter from the log-normal distribution. I want to control the amount of "noise" with the value of the CV and see what impact such variable parameters have on my simulation results. Should I just empirically increase the CV before the simulations such that on average my n samples have the desired CV, if I would compute it after the simulations?

Its presently unclear what the value in doing that would be. It might be better to describe the problem you're doing this to solve rather than the problem with your attempted solution. That is, it might be better to describe the issue with parameter choice for your simulation that you're doing all this for. {It sounds like an XY problem} ... it may be better to seek advice for approaching that differently

But in any case, if you're sampling the distribution with the desired CV for your inputs, its unclear why properties of some particular sample estimator of that CV is of interest.

Let mes explain my setup better: I am simulating a stochastic reaction diffusion equation on a cellular domain. Now I draw random kinetic parameters for each cell. These kinetic parameters are drawn from log-normal distributions. Now the variance is inputed by the CV, using the known formulas for log-normal distributions. This means that each cell has a set of distinct kinetic parameters. If I calculate the CV from the mean and std from these sampled kinetic parameters, I get a big underestimation of the CV. How can I correct for this?

Please also edit this information into the question. However, what I said  above is unchanged. Why would the bias in a biased sample estimate matter for this?
